# Display image only when we start editing Text

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an UIImage and TextField. When user starts writing in TextField Image must be displayed and when the user is done with writing in that TextField UIImage must Hide.
How to do it?

What I tried is :

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    heartImg.isHidden = false
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    heartImg.isHidden = true
}
```

Comment: Use Textfield delegate method and use it your requirement when you want to hide or show

Comment: Have you even searched ?

Comment: I did tried following :func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
       
        heartImg.isHidden = false
        
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        
        heartImg.isHidden = true
        
    }

Comment: make sure to set the delegate of your textfield: self.textField.delegate = self

Comment: What was the output you got with your code ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.background = UIImage(named: "focus.png")
    return true
}

func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.background = UIImage(named: "nofocus.png")
    return true
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

**OR set image on rightView/ leftview**

```
textField.rightViewMode = .unlessEditing
textField.leftView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "textfield_edit_icon.png"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a delegate to the UITextfield, here you are able to get notified for certain delegate methods:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate

In your case, it is:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619590-textfielddidbeginediting

Implement this function in your delegate's class and you can now set your image to be visible / not hidden anymore within this method.

You can hide it also on "end editing":

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
```

https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619591-textfielddidendediting

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Add a image view as leftView to your TextField.

And set that textfield leftViewMode as .whileEditing

```
    let LeftView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "yourImage")
    yourTextfield.leftView = LeftView
    yourTextfield.leftViewMode = .whileEditing
```